# notifyItemChanged call onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I've a strange problem with my recyclerView adapter, I just want to show/hide ImageView depending of the selection but when I call the `notifyItemChanged(selection)` in my click listener, it call `onCreateViewHolder` and take a delay to refresh de view, I don't know why and I didn't find another solution to perform what I need.

This is my adapter:

```
public class ChannelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelAdapter.ChannelHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Integer> channelList;
    private Integer selection = 0;

    public ChannelAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> channelList) {
        this.channelList = channelList;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ChannelHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: ");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_channel_item_selected, parent, false);
        ChannelHolder holder = new ChannelHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChannelHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+position);
        holder.textViewChannelId.setText("#"+channelList.get(position));
        holder.textViewChannel.setText(channelList.get(position).toString());

        if(position==selection){
            holder.imageViewSelectorLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imageViewSelectorRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            holder.imageViewSelectorLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.imageViewSelectorRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channelList.size();
    }

    public class ChannelHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewChannel, textViewChannelId;
        ImageView imageViewSelectorLeft, imageViewSelectorRight;

        public ChannelHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewChannelId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChannelId);
            textViewChannel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChannel);
            imageViewSelectorLeft = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSelectorLeft);
            imageViewSelectorRight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSelectorRight);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                notifyItemChanged(selection);
                selection=getAdapterPosition();
                notifyItemChanged(selection);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Do I miss something or am I doing it by the wrong way?
Thanks in advance for any help

**Edit :**
I tried to use `notifyItemChanged` with a payload set to 1 and override `onBindViewHolder` to get the payload but it still call `onCreateViewHolder`, even when `mSupportsChangeAnimations` is set to false

Comment: Use `notifyItemChanged(position, payload)` and override `onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)`.

Comment: Already try by setting payload to 1 and override method but it still call `onCreateViewHolder`

Answer (score 2):

By default, your RecyclerView will have a `DefaultItemAnimator` attached to it. When you call `notifyItemChanged()` on your adapter, the system will eventually call through to the `DefaultItemAnimator` to find out whether it needs to create a new `ViewHolder` or if it can "re-use" the existing one.

```
@Override
public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder,
        @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
    return !payloads.isEmpty() || super.canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder, payloads);
}
```

The superclass implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    return !mSupportsChangeAnimations || viewHolder.isInvalid();
}
```

These suggest that there are two easy ways to make sure that the `ViewHolder` is reused instead of recreated:

- Make sure that the `payloads` list is not empty. This is done by calling `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position, payload)`. It doesn't matter what the `payload` is, as long as it is non-null.
- Set `mSupportsChangeAnimations` to `false` for your `DefaultItemAnimator`.

```
DefaultItemAnimator animator = (DefaultItemAnimator) recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
animator.setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Comment: Thanks you for this explanation, I `setSupportsChangeAnimation` to false in my recycler, and set payload to 1 when calling `notifyItemChanged` but it still call `onCreateViewHolder` when I select an item...
I've try to Override onBindViewHolder method with the payloads args but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! This works!!! The nuances of recyclerview are really hard to understand,. Was struggling a lot to understand why the onCreateViewHolder was being called on notifyItemChanged(). Excellent explanation!!!

Comment: @Ben P. What If I'm using `RecyclerView.Adapter` with `ViewPager2` ? I can pass `payload` when `notifyItemChanged` , but I believe there's no 'DefaultItemAnimator '. Any idea how to stop the adapter from calling `onCreateViewHolder` ? Thanks

Comment: Also, BTW `onCreateViewHolder` is called only first time `notifyItemChanged` is called. If I call `notifyItemChanged` again for the same "position" or different one, only `onBindViewHolder` is called as desired. This is when using `ViewPager2`

Answer (score -1):

You can call your adapter like this

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(yourList, yourActivity.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and then you can put this code on itemClick in adapter

```
if(position==getAdapterPosition()){
        holder.imageViewSelectorLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageViewSelectorRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        holder.imageViewSelectorLeft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.imageViewSelectorRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how what you say is suppose to help me, what I've to do with `yourActivity.this` in my adapter constructor? 
And what about the `onItemClick`? It's not clear...

Comment: yourActivity.this is the context passing to the adapter if you are passing. If you are not passing the context to the Adapter then skip this. yourActivity.this is the context passing to the adapter and on item click paste the above code hope that working

Comment: I know that but I don't see how it supposed to help me to avoid the call of `onCreateViewHolder` when I use `onItemChange`